# How to find the average distance from one corner of a triangle to the opposite side?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have a triangle geometry question.

Given the known coordinates of all corners of a triangle, how would you go about working out the average distance from one corner of the triangle to the opposite side? So, in this image, the average length of dashed line if angles between them are kept constant/infinitely small.

[image]

I figure this must be an established formula, but I can’t track it down. Something a bit like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207275/triangle-trigonometry-finding-the-distance-between-a-corner-and-any-point-on-t), maybe? Or related to the geometric mean? But I am not exactly a math pro... I am hoping to write this into a c++ sketch.

In hope
Sam

Update (26/10/21):
Hi Folks, thanks for the replies! I really appreciate them, although I am struggling to fully understand them, being not exactly literate in math notation. But trying to work through them.

As an update, I was doing a little more thinking on this last night and thought of the following - would be great if someone could comment on if it is technically sound:

- Perhaps the average length from the angle to the opposite line, is equal to the radius of a circle segment of matching area to the triangle?
- So: first find triangle area ’T'
- Find angle theta between lines (in radians)
- Find ratio of theta to a full circle: 2Pi/theta
- Multiply by triangle area to get hypothetical circle area: (2Pi*T)/theta
- This equals circle area or Pi*r_sq
- So: (2Pi*T)/theta = Pi*r_sq
- Therefore 2T/theta = r_sq

So the average length should be **sq_rt(2T/theta)**?

Does this work as an answer? it seems logical to me, and I can understand the maths... Perhaps it is the same as some of the answers below?

Comments welcome!
S

Comment: You should realise that the answer critically depends on which kind of sampling you have in mind. If you want angles among distances to be equally spaced, as you seem to suggest in the figure, then my answer gives the solution. If you want the points those distances intercept on side $c$ to be equally spaced, you'll have another result, an so on. A "purely geometric" answer does not exist.

Comment: And of course the "average" you propose gives another different answer.

Comment: But if any kind of average works for you, then you could simply choose the arithmetic mean of $a$ and $b$. Simple and fast.

Answer (score 1):

You want the average distance between a point on the line

$p(t) = A + t (B - A) $ where $0 \lt t \lt 1$

and the point C.

The distance, by the distance formula, is

$d(t) = \sqrt{ (p(t) - C) \cdot (p(t) - C ) } $

Expanding, and letting $V_1 = C - A $ and $V_2 = B - A $, then

$d(t) = \sqrt{ V_1 \cdot V_1 - 2 t V_1 \cdot V_2 + t^2 V_2 \cdot V_2 }$

And the average distance is by definition,

$\overline{d} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 d(t) dt $

If $V_1 \cdot V_1 = a^2 $ and $V_2 \cdot V_2 = b^2 $ then $V_1 \cdot V_2 = a b \cos \theta $ where $\theta $ is the angle between $V_1 $ and $V_2 $

$\overline{d} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \sqrt{a^2 - 2 a b \cos \theta t + t^2 b^2 } $

Which can be integrated by completing the square.

$\overline{d} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \sqrt{ (b t - a \cos \theta )^2 + a^2 \sin^2 \theta } $

By the substitution:  $ a \sin \theta \tan u = b t - a \cos \theta $

It is kind of messy nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how helpful this answer is, but here is how I would proceed.

Move, scale and rotate the triangle $C,A,B$ (with special corner $C$) in such a way that the triangle becomes $C'=(0,0), A'= (1,0)$ and $B' = (x_0, y_0)$. Consider the ray $r$ defined by $y=\tan (\alpha) x$, where $\alpha \in [0, \arctan(\frac{y_0}{x_0})]$, which eminates at $C'$ with an angle of $\alpha$ from the side $\overline{C'A'}$.

Calculations show that the intersection point $P$ of the ray $r$ with the side $\overline{A'B'}$ is
$$
P_\alpha= \left(1-\frac{x_0-1}{y_0}\tan(\alpha), \ \ \frac{y_0}{x_0-1}-\tan(\alpha) \right).
$$
and thus the distance from $C'$ to $P_\alpha$ is $|P_\alpha|$. (Note that if $x_0 = 1$, then $P=(1,\tan(\alpha))$ and the formula above does not work.)

Now the proper way to calculate the average distance would be to calculate the integral
$$
D = \frac{1}{\arctan(\frac{y_0}{x_0})}\int_{0}^{\arctan(\frac{y_0}{x_0})} |P_\alpha| \text{d}\alpha
$$
As this likely does not have a nice formula as a solution, one would need to approximate this value.

To get the average distance from $C$ to $\overline{AB}$ in the original triangle, you have to scale this length up to get
$$
L = D \cdot |A-C|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

As you need "the average length of dashed lines if angles between them are kept constant", I suppose you want to sample the lengths uniformly with respect to the angle $\theta$ they form with side $a$. If $\beta$ is the angle opposite side $b$ and $\gamma$ is the angle opposite side $c$, then the length $x(\theta)$ of a dashed line can be computed by the sine rule:
$$
x(\theta)=a{\sin\beta\over\sin(\beta+\theta)}.
$$
Hence its average value is:
$$
\bar x={1\over\gamma}\int_0^\gamma x(\theta)\,d\theta
=a{\sin\beta\over\gamma}
\ln\left(\cot{\beta\over2}\tan{\beta+\gamma\over2}\right),
$$
where angles must be in radians.

Comment: I corrected a typo in the answer. Note that angle $\gamma$ in front of the last formula must be given in radians.